# How to change the color of hyperlink text in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinymce link plugin to add link in text area . I want to change the hyperlink text into a distinguishable text ( color change and bold in style ). how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this via CSS.  There is a setting for TinyMCE called `content_css`

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

...this allows you to pass any CSS you like to TinyMCE to control how the content is styled.  You could then change the styles on all links:

```
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: If that solved the issue can you please accept this answer so others know the issue is resolved?